# C/C++ library for computing color difference (delta E) and color space conversions

Tags: c++, c, colors

I googled but didn't find anything. I'm using colormath library for python, but it rather slow.

Answer (score 2):

I've written code for this in Javascript.  It's very easy to translate to C!

See `deltaE2000()`, which takes colors in LCHab, and perhaps the functions to convert RGB -> Linear RGB -> XYZ-> Lab -> LCHab.  [Code](http://svn.int64.org/viewvc/int64/colors/colors.js), and [UI demo](http://svn.int64.org/viewvc/int64/colors/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try http://github.com/dmilos/color

Code sample:

```
typedef ::color::rgb<double> color_t; // or lab or hsv or any other available model

color_t a = ::color::constant::orange_t{};      
color_t b = ::color::constant::chocolate_t{};

std::cout << ::color::operation::distance< ::color::constant::distance::CIE94_textile_entity >( a, b ) << std::endl;
std::cout << ::color::operation::distance< ::color::constant::distance::CIEDE2000_entity >( a, b ) << std::endl;
```

Other examples with other algorithms:

https://github.com/dmilos/color/tree/master/example/less-than-1k/operation/distance

Color model is irrelevant. It will be automatically convert internally.

All formulas are documented at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this library for personal use:

https://github.com/ThunderStruct/Color-Utilities

Both the header and the cpp files are less than 5kb, so this might be useful if you don't want to clutter your project with a larger library

Here's a sample:

```
// Colors' construction
ColorUtils::rgbColor c1(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), c2(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

// Calculate Delta-E using CIE76
std::cout << ColorUtils::getColorDeltaE(c1, c2) << '\n';
```

This outputs `46.8072` (you may validate the results using [this](http://colormine.org/delta-e-calculator) converter)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) will probably do.

Comment: [`cvCvtColor` function](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00054000000000000000)

Comment: It doesn't. OpenCV misses Delte E functions and its cvtColor() function operates on images which is inconvenient if you want to convert only one color value.

Comment: Can't you calculate this quite easily with the Lab color space? Also, what do you mean by 'convert only color value'?

Comment: @stnr “convert only one color value.” Not the colors of the entire image, but that of a single pixel.